# Access 2019: EMF file support just gone?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an Access report (to produce my invoices :) with a EMF file (Enhanced Meta File) set as report background, so I can print it or PDF it and it looks like it was made on preprinted business paper.

I know I produced a perfect PDF last month (end of May 2019) with it, but today June 30, the background graphics are gone. I tested that on 2 PCS, same result.
I restored an early May version (before it generated that perfectly looking invoice at end of May) of the MDB, same result.
Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real explanation, but I solved the issue using these steps:

- imported all abjects into a fresh accdb  --> no change
- installed Inkscape
- opened the .emf file I had saved
- saved it as again as .emf (new name)
- updated the report's Picture property to the newly saved file
- solved

I had 2 reports in the db, both had the same issue, and both were fixed using the same procedure.

Strange... I just hope anyone with a similar issue can explain this or use the info.  I have been working for 15 years on VBA and Access development, and I have no explanation.